# Django ModuleNotFoundError on Heroku Release

Tags: python, django, heroku

Similar to many previously stated issues yet unresolved in my case, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError` when deploying my Django project for release on Heroku, which works fine locally. I use `Django 4.0` and `Python 3.10.13`.

Heroku release log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 413, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 454, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 486, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/compatibility/django_4_0.py", line 9, in check_csrf_trusted_origins
    for origin in settings.CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 89, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 76, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 190, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'opportunities.settings.heroku_staging'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/app/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 426, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 84, in close_all
    for conn in self.all(initialized_only=True):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 76, in all
    return [
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 73, in __iter__
    return iter(self.settings)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 47, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 45, in settings
    self._settings = self.configure_settings(self._settings)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 148, in configure_settings
    databases = super().configure_settings(databases)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 50, in configure_settings
    settings = getattr(django_settings, self.settings_name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 89, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 76, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 190, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'opportunities.settings.heroku_staging'
```

The project structure is currently as follows:
[image]

In Heroku, I have `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` set to `opportunities.settings.heroku_staging`. So ogiven the project structure that should do the trick but I get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're deploying your project in a module `app` and not `opportunities`, given the file paths in the traceback (e.g. `File "/app/manage.py", line 22, in <module>`).

You can:

1. Change your config to deploy on `opportunities` instead of `app`. How to do this depends on how you're deploying it.
2. Or set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`  to `app.settings.heroku_staging`.

Comment: I don’t think that’s the issue because ‘app’ is simply the default folder where heroku builds the apps. The root is within that folder and I never had to go one level above for previously deployed apps. I gave it a try anyway and the error remains but for ‘app’ this time